# trabajar un combobox en netbens

Tags: java

soy estudiante y necesito ayuda, tengo un formulario el cual tiene opcion de ingresar un usuario y un combobox en netbens usando lenguaje java , se puede llenar con datos de la base de datos este combobox el cual es solo el nombre del cargo,se pueden ver dentro de este , pero no puedo guardar el dato seleccionado por este, también me aparece un error por favor ayudarme.base de datos tiene usuario(com sus atributos y también cargo(fk()99)) y cargo(idcargo(pk)(99) y nombrecargo).
código :

```
 try{
        
        Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:
   //localhost/sistemaherramientas","root","");
    Statement sent=con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs= sent.executeQuery("select * from cargo");
        
    //    ccargo.addItem("seleccione un Cargo");
        
     while(rs.next()){
            
     this.ccargo.addItem(rs.getString("nombrecargo"));
            
        }
        contador++;
    
    
       }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);

    }
                                 
      
     }

     public void InsertarDatos(){
         
    try {       
    
    String SQL="insert into usuario(rutfuncionario,nombrefuncionario,
     cargo,fechamodificacion,contrasena) values (?,?,?,?,?)";
    PreparedStatement pst=con.prepareStatement(SQL);
        
        pst.setString(1,txtrut.getText()); 
        pst.setString(2,txtnombre.getText());
     int selecionado=ccargo.getSelectedIndex();
   pst.setString(3,ccargo.getItemAt(selecionado));                     
               
         pst.setString(4,txtfecha.getText());
        pst.setString(5,mEncoder.ecnode(txtcontraseña.getText()));
                              
         pst.execute();
        
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se agrego el registro"); 
              
                       } catch (Exception e){
    
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "error registro" +e.getMessage());
     }
     }

       private void ccargoActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    
    try{
        if(this.contador>0){
        Connection con1= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost
           /sistemaherramientas","root","");
        Statement sent1= con1.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs1 = sent1.executeQuery("select * from cargo where 
           nombrecargo='"+this.ccargo.getSelectedItem()+"'");
        rs1.next();
 
        
        }
    
    }
    
    
    catch(Exception e){
    
     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
     
    
    
    }
       
        
  }
```

[image: Error que muestra al ejecutar el archivo]

Comment: Bienvenido/a a [es.so], haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio, y lee [ask]. Pon el error _como texto con formato_, ya que se dificulta verlo en imagen. Además, ten en cuenta que el IDE (Netbeans) no tiene nada que ver en la pregunta, y que el título de la misma debe ser más descriptivo, para que los demás usuarios puedan ayudarte más fácilmente. Pulsa en [edit] para mejorar tu pregunta.

Comment: El error que muestras parece claro. En la base de datos el campo cargo está definido como un entero, probablemente el id de la tabla cargo, y tú estás intentando insertar ahí una cadena de texto, "administracion". La idea es que en addItem no añadas un String directamente sino un objecto que te crees que contenga el id del cargo y su descripción. De forma que cuando selecciones un item, puedas recuperar ese id. Aquí explican a qué me refiero aunque está en inglés https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17887927/adding-items-to-a-jcombobox